# How to use multiple jssor slider on a single page

Tags: jssor

I want to use multiple jssor slider on a single page. However, it is working only with div id = "jssor_1".

Can you please suggest on how to use multiple jsson slider on a single page?

Thank you in advance,
Rajesh

Answer (score 0):

Each slider should have an unique id.

If the first is jssor_1, you can set the id of the second slider to jssor_2.
And make sure to replace all 'jssor_1' with 'jssor_2'.

Here is an option `ID` to make slider with different id easily.

See [Options](http://www.jssor.com/help/options.html)